# Can a Deployment controller control Pods that weren't created by it?

Tags: kubernetes

Say I have a pod YAML such as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.19.1
```

And a Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.17.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Now I first create the Pod:

```
$ kubectl apply -f pod.yaml
```

And only then the Deployment:

```
$ kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

I thought that, since the pod.yaml metadata includes a `app: nginx` selector, the Deployment controller will only create 2 nginx:1.17.1 pods, but I see that all 3 are created. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to creating the `app: nginx` label, Deployment controller also added the `pod-template-hash` label for each pod that was created.

If we check labels for running pods, we can see `pod-template-hash=5d5dd5dd49` label for my-deployment pods:

```
$ kubectl get pods --show-labels
NAME    READY   STATUS   RESTARTS   AGE     LABELS
my-deployment-5d5dd5dd49-9tbcx 1/1 Running 0 55s app=nginx,pod-template-hash=5d5dd5dd49
my-deployment-5d5dd5dd49-b88f4 1/1 Running 0 55s app=nginx,pod-template-hash=5d5dd5dd49
my-deployment-5d5dd5dd49-x7n8q 1/1 Running 0 55s app=nginx,pod-template-hash=5d5dd5dd49
nginx                          1/1 Running 0 62s app=nginx
```

According to the [official documentation:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#pod-template-hash-label)

> The `pod-template-hash` label ensures that child ReplicaSets of a Deployment do not
> overlap. It is generated by hashing the  `PodTemplate`  of the
> ReplicaSet and using the resulting hash as the label value that is
> added to the ReplicaSet selector, Pod template labels, and in any
> existing Pods that the ReplicaSet might have.

This is why the changes from the Deployment didn't apply to a single pod with only the `app: nginx` label.

Comment: so why do we even need to specify labels in the Deployment's `.template.metadata.labels` and to then select it in the Deployment's `.spec.selector.matchLabels`? What is this good for?

Comment: .spec.selector is a required field that specifies a label selector for the Pods targeted by this Deployment.

.spec.selector must match .spec.template.metadata.labels, or it will be rejected by the API.

[The .spec.selector field defines how the Deployment finds which Pods to manage.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment)
During rollouts only one label from your example will be not changed - app: nginx, since with every new deployment ReplicaSet will be created with new hash from pod template. Only this label can be used as constant.